# WordPress failure when logging out

Tags: logout, nonce

I have came across the WordPress logout error several times but I really never figured out the cause of it. In earlier days, it was generally that I was missing a nonce but now even with logout link generated by `wp_logout_url();`, I am greeted with the WP die screen:

```
You are attempting to log out of SITE
Do you really want to log out?
```

What causes this to trigger at the first place?

**Edit:** Like I mentioned it was happening randomly, I think I figured out something. IT works fine with link generated by `wp_logout_url();` but as soon as I use a `$redirect` parameter in `wp_logout_url( $redirect );`, I start facing the issue.

Any light on the matter?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Emerson Nope! And didn't ran into again. I mean didn't have to use it after that.

Comment: have you set an `exit()` after the redirect?

Comment: @kaiser I wasn't manually redirecting here. Just letting the function know that it should redirect. I guess the function would be doing / is supposed to `exit()` after redirecting, but I didn't check the source when I had this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is raised by `wp_nonce_ays()` which is called by `check_admin_referer()`.

Your browser has probably not sent a referer header, so WordPress could not validate the nonce. This may be a problem in your browser settings or your network connection.

Comment: So its totally a hiccup and nothing else?

Comment: Impossible to tell _for sure_ without seeing it. But it seems to be random … you may sit behind a proxy that changes your request headers.