# Wordpress error on log out 'Not Permitted' and can't log out

Tags: login, errors, wp-login-form, logout

I've got a weird situation whereby I sometimes can't log in as clicking on a link (or going  directly) to /wp-login.php shows me a blank page with the words 'Not Permitted'.

If I go to the /wp-login.php page directly from that 'Not Permitted' page, then I can log in using my details. If I try and log out again though, I reach that 'Not Permitted' page again and can't log out.

That's a bit long-winded, so I've created a video so you can see what I mean:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI3NTiGNgoE

Has anyone come across this before? This is the first time I've seen this type of error, I've seen the 'are you sure you want to log out' error message before, but not this one...

Thanks

Osu

Comment: This is not a WordPress message. Disable all plugins and switch to Twenty Twelve. Does it still happen?

Comment: Hi @toscho - thanks for this. I can't do that I'm afraid, this is a live site so I can't just switch things over, at least not until a quiet period. If it's not a Wordpress issue then I'll need to take it up with the host I guess. Have you come across this before?

Comment: If you can't debug, that makes it hard. I have never seen that message, for what is worth. You could try clearing the domain cookies. That might help, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Ok, I'll switch the theme and disabled the plugins later this evening so there's minimal disruption. I was hoping I could try something in wp-config.php or my functions.php, but I'll try toscho's suggestion first. Thanks.

Comment: @Osu ... if someone happens to recognize that message you are in luck. Otherwise it is going to have to be narrowed down by trial and error. Sorry. That is painful on a production server. Also, do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) that you could provide?

Comment: You could try firebug, it may give more insight into what is happening as regards returned headers, redirects...

Comment: Incidentally (probably), I'm unable to "Okay, thanks" the cookie warning at the top.

Comment: This related post was in the sidebar: WordPress failure when logging out - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/wordpress-failure-when-logging-out?rq=1

Comment: @s_ha_dum - I enabled debugging briefly to see if there are any signs of errors and have this: http://pastie.org/7704075 I'm thinking the head error messages is something to do with this...

Comment: That does suggest a plugin problem, though finding it still requires following toscho's advice from the first comment.

Comment: I doubt those notice level errors are the cause of this issue.

Comment: As soon as I've tried switching the theme and disabling the plugins I'll report my findings here. Thanks for all your help so far, it's much appreciated

Comment: Ok, I deactivated the theme and all plugins, but still had the same problem. I also encountered an issue when trying to reactivate the theme where I couldn't access the admin end (Server Error, but with no details), so had to rename my theme folder, activate all the plugins first, then rename the theme folder and reactivate that again. I've got the feeling it could be something to do with the SSL certificate I'm using or maybe Paid Memberships Pro plugin and Wordpress which uses that SSL...

Comment: Again - try firebug to get more insight into returned headers and redirects.

Comment: @vancoder - thanks for your continued patience with this. What should I be looking out for specifically in Firebug? I usually use Chrome for web development, is there something in Chrome I could try?

Comment: I recently saw some of the bigger hosting companies globally disabling all wordpress logins due to the current attacks using some rather obscure filtering methods. If you are on shared hosting, that might be the case here, too. In chrome you just have to open the developer panel `Ctrl + Shift + i` and then switch to network and refresh the page, you can then change the filter (at the bottom) to "Documents". The interesting information is what status code (403?) is returned and if there is any redirect happening.

Comment: Thanks @s1lv3r - I've spoken with the hosting company who have told me that they have a mod security measure in place that 'will allow only 8 requests to wp-login.php within 30 seconds and then they are rate limited and no longer able to make any further requests'. Their solution is to disable this, but considering they say 'more than 8 number of logins normally happen when there is someone trying to hack into the site using WP admin login page', I'm pretty reluctant to authorise them to do that! Do you know if there might be another better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an answer out of this now to give a more detailed write-up to your question.

As the botnet is so large and the attack is happening with so much IPs (some providers say they have seen >90.000 different addresses) it makes no sense anymore to start blocking single IPs (using plugins like Limit Login Attempts or fail2ban at the server side) like we did in the past.

Your hosting company is quite right. Your page maybe is under attack. Like almost all other wordpress installations in the moment are also under attack. But they implemented a solution that's actually preventing you from working with your wordpress install.

The only ***REAL*** solution in the moment is to have a strong password that cannot be brute-forced (optionally don't even have a username `admin`). If you ***really*** have a safe password you can tell your provider to disable that limitation without ***any*** worries.

---

Also following a long discussion at the wp-hackers mailinglist, Sam Hotchkiss actually came up with a plugin called [BruteProtect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bruteprotect/) you could additionally use. This plugin logs all failed logins from any wordpress install this plugin is installed on and blocks any IP that has to many failed attempts.

Comment: Thanks for this @s1lv3r - I think this is the solution for the timebeing so have marked your answer as the correct one. By the way, how would I change the username 'admin'? I thought that wasn't possible?