# How To Change Logout Screen Title

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I'd like to change the title of my Wordpress logout screen.

[image]

I plan to use a filter on 'wp_login_errors' to change the body text but I don't know how to change the page title from "Wordpress Failure Notice".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you see this page it means you're doing logout in a wrong way. The `check_admin_referer()` fails and calls `wp_nonce_ays()`, thus prompting for a confirmation (**ays** = **A**re **Y**ou **S**ure?). See these threads for more details:

- [How to log out without confirmation 'Do you really want to log out?"?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/how-to-log-out-without-confirmation-do-you-really-want-to-log-out/222624#222624)
- [WordPress failure when logging out](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/wordpress-failure-when-logging-out)
- [wp_logout_url() - WordPress Failure Notice](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152950/wp-logout-url-wordpress-failure-notice)

Finding and eliminating the cause of the problem may be the best way to go.

The text string itself is on line 2607 of wp-includes/functions.php:

```
wp_die( $html, __( 'WordPress Failure Notice' ), 403 );
```

As you see, there's no filter. However, it's a string passed to `__()` function, which means you can filter it using `gettext`:

```
function wpse283987_change_string( $translated_text, $untranslated_text ) {

    global $pagenow;

    if( $pagenow === 'wp-login.php' && $untranslated_text === 'WordPress Failure Notice' ) {
        return __( 'Your New Text' );
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse283987_change_string', 20, 2 );
```